# Close all open modal dialog windows

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application that has several modal window used for various purposes.  This is easily accomplished by using the `ShowDialog` function.  However, in my application I have a timer to measure idle time (i.e. no mouse moves or key strokes) that will cause the user to be logged off.  Is there a way (when this timer fires) to find and close all open modal windows without tracking each explicitly?

**Update**
I would also like to close any MessageBox.Show instances.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way (when this timer fires) to find and close all open modal windows without tracking each explicitly?

You could use [ComponentDispatcher.IsThreadModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.isthreadmodal.aspx) to check to see if you're UI thread is in a modal state.  If it is, the [Application.Current.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) property will give you the list of opened Windows.

If you only have a single MainWindow, you could close any others (as they'd be your modal dialogs), but if you have multiple windows, you'd have to check each one.

Unfortunately, there's no direct API to determine whether a specific Window is modal - but there is a private variable in the Window class you could use to do this.  For example, the following method uses reflection to determine whether a Window is modal:

```
  public static bool IsModal(Window window)
  {
       Type type = typeof(Window);
       var field = type.GetField("_showingAsDialog", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
       return field.GetValue(window);
  }
```

This is, unfortunately, subject to change (since it's using undocumented private members).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I wasn't aware of the Application.Current.Windows property.  Also, I appreciate the information about the _showingAsDialog field.  That looks like the ticket.  I updated my question to include MessageBox instances.  Do you know how to close those in a similar fashion?

Comment: @Matt: Unfortunately, MessageBox.Show is probably going to require a P/Invoke call, since they don't have a Window you can access...  If you're going to have to handle that, too, you might want to either re-think your design here, or look at calling PInvoke with EnumWindows and similar methods to track all open windows...

Comment: Thanks.  I think we'll try to convert all of the MessageBox calls to windows, which when combined with your answer should solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to iterate the Application.Current.Windows collection, and close all these that are not the Application.Current.MainWindow?

Jogy

Comment: I just did this based on a thread I found on the MSDN forums, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/86e4806f-8f95-49a8-811e-e01514518e16

Comment: I updated my question to include MessageBoxes.  Do you know how to close those in a similar fashion?