# How to handle locking an application while a modal dialog is open?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The application I am working on uses modal dialogs. I am currently implementing a session timeout that automatically locks the screen after a certain number of inactive minutes, but I ran into an issue where if user has a modal dialog open, it shows on top of the session locked screen.

What is the general logic to use to identify and force-close any modal dialogs (using Cancel action) in a WPF .Net application?

Comment: If there is no problem closing the modal i would suggest using a cron job from the Modal, to check some variable of the parent that determine if the session is locked, then you can simply call a close method in your modal. If not you could check your modal variable, and invoke the close from  another thread .

Comment: @nalnpir I thought about that, but there are so many places within the application that show modal dialogs. Some are generic such as OpenFileDialog or a MessageBox, and others are more complex such as custom dialogs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093899/close-all-open-modal-dialog-windows check the answer from Jogy, perhaps thats exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @nalnpir Thanks, that's a good direction to look in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some intricacies to modal dialogs which are best illustrated through example. The following handler spawns a new `Window` on click, followed by a `MessageBox`, waits for a second and then closes both. Note we want `MainWindow` to stay open.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const int timeout = 1000;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = new Window { Content = new Label { Content = "Not a modal Window" } };

        using (new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, win, timeout, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            win.Show();

            MessageBox.Show($"Open windows: {Application.Current.Windows.Count}", "Just a sec...");
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                ((Window)state).Close();
            }));
    }
}
```

The main take-away from this example is that both the non-modal window and the MessageBox are closed. However, if we take a closer look at `OnTimerElapsed` we see that only the non-modal window is told to close. Given that's the window that was the (last) one active at the time `MessageBox.Show` was called, it is also the owner of the MessageBox, hence closing it closes the MessageBox as well.

We could replace the line `MessageBox.Show(...);` with `new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog();` and get similar results.

That brings us to the top level. What if we want to close a MessageBox which is instantiated from the main window, how can we achieve that without closing both? One option is to create a dummy owner window, which is never *shown*, but merely acts as a reference to call `Close` upon.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const int timeout = 1000;
    private Window _modalOwner;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeModalOwner();
    }

    private void InitializeModalOwner()
    {
        _modalOwner = new Window
        {
            AllowsTransparency = true,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            Background = Brushes.Transparent
        };
        _modalOwner.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, null, timeout, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_modalOwner, $"Open windows: {Application.Current.Windows.Count}", "Just a sec...");
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
                foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows)
                    if(win != mainWindow)
                        win.Close();
                InitializeModalOwner();
            }));
    }
}
```

Here we iterate all windows in the current `WindowCollection` and close them as long as they're not the main window of our application. After which `_modalOwner` will also have been closed, rendering it useless -- you can't call `Show` on a `Window` instance once it's been closed. So this is also the place to initialize it again.

The same goes for `new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog(_modalOwner);`. Any `Window` instances on which you call `ShowDialog` will automatically be added to the `Application.Current.Windows` collection.

Resources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner#remarks
- [how to set wpf MessageBox.Owner to desktop window because SplashScreen closes MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576503/how-to-set-wpf-messagebox-owner-to-desktop-window-because-splashscreen-closes-me#comment63416285_10854591)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying your second solution of having a hidden window for the modal dialog owner, but I am getting an exception when trying to close it - `Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed`. I'm not entirely sure what's trying to set visibility, unless perhaps it's something to do with the adorner windows...

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I had to add a check so `&& (win.GetType().FullName != "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow"`. Still, your proof of concept seems good. Now to see how I can work it into the application I'm working on. I'm only looking to close modal dialogs, and not all windows. Thanks!